# Deleting Subvectors in a Multidimensional Vector after Checking for Doubles

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, multidimensional-array

I have created a container with several combinations of a three dimensional vector. Structure looks similar to this:

```
combinations[4096][4][4][4]; // only want to show element number here
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>> combinations; // used in my code
```

My problem currently is that I am not sure how I can delete all the double vectors in the combinations container. So far I have tried this:

```
for(int i=0; i<combinations.size(); i++){
    // Counter Part Combinations
    for(int j=0; j<combinations.size(); j++){
        if (j!=i) {
            if (combinations[i]==combinations[j]) {
                combinations.erase(combinations.begin()+j*64, combinations.begin()+(j+1)*64);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `std::set<vector <vector <vector<type> > >` ?

Comment: I have used subvectors therefore I think it becomes clear that I have used this type ...

Comment: I did not get any serious comments here only downvotes. No idea what this is here ...

Comment: Oh, that I missed. I have no idea why you get downvoted, but here, take my upvote.

Comment: Thanks still hoping that someone can help me out.

Comment: @Philipp Braun What is the combination? Is it a three-dimensional subvector? Do you need to have a vector of unique three-dimensional subvectors?

Comment: This example does not appear that difficult, however, it doesn't appear you've given us enough information to be useful. Please provide a short compilable example.

Comment: like stated in the description combinations is a multidimensional vector containing several three-dimensional subvectors

Comment: @Varaquilex please strive to upvote questions because they are useful, clear, and show research effort.  Don't vote to "undo" someone else's vote.

Comment: What are "double vectors"?  What is a "combinations container"?  What was the result of what you tried?

Comment: @PhilippBraun Did you possibly mean "duplicate" vectors rather than "double" vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood correctly then the code snippet can look like

```
auto last = combinations.begin();
for ( auto current = combinations.begin(); current != combinations.end(); ++current )
{
    auto first = combinations.begin();
    while ( first != last && *first != *current ) ++first;

    if ( first == last )
    {
        if ( last == current ) ++last;
        else *last++ = *current;
    }
}

combinations.erase( last, combinations.end() );
```

The inner loop can be substituted for standard algorithm `std::find`. For example

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

//... 

auto last = combinations.begin();
for ( auto current = combinations.begin(); current != combinations.end(); ++current )
{
    if ( std::find( combinations.begin(), last, *current ) == last )
    {
        if ( last == current ) ++last;
        else *last++ = *current;
    }
}

combinations.erase( last, combinations.end() );
```

I suppose that the original vector shall not be sorted. Otherwise you could sort it and apply algorithm `std::unique`.